# WEBサイトのメールフォームにクレジットカードの補完がでないようにしたい

Tags: html

ホームページのお問い合わせメールフォームの名前入力時に
クレジットカード情報が表示されます。
これを非表示にさせることは出来ないものでしょうか？
cssやhtml、jsで解決できるものなのでしょうか？

ホームページ制作後、お問い合わせフォームの確認していたところ
一人の方から、クレジットカード情報が名前入力時に表示されるとの内容でした
名前入力部分のコードは下記のとおりです

```
<dt>名前<span>Your Name</span></dt>
<dd class="required">
  <input type="text" id="name_1" name="name_1" value=""　autocomplete="off" /> 
  <input type="text" id="name_2" name="name_2" value=""　autocomplete="off" />
</dd>
```

クレジットカード情報が名前入力時に表示される方は、マイクロソフトエッジを利用しています。
Chromeやfirefoxなどで見ている人はクレジットカード情報が表示されません

クレジットカード情報を非表示にすることは出来ないものでしょうか？
autocompleteのことを色々検索し、autocomplete=none や jsでのautocomplete=off も
行ったのですが全く解決しませんでした

対応策がお分かりの方がおられましたら、ご回答のほど、よろしくお願いします

Comment: 「クレジットカード情報が表示される」というのは[この画像](https://usedoor.jp/wp-content/uploads/windows10/edge/creditcard-kakunin-touroku-sakujo/microsoft-edge-creditcard-jouhou-020.png)のようにテキストボックスの下にクレジットカードの補完候補が出るということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、nekketsuuさんのお話のような画像のクレジットカードの補完候補です

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozillaが開発者向けに[フォームの自動補完を無効にするには](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)というドキュメントを公開しています。

> 現代的なブラウザーの多くはログイン欄における `autocomplete="off"` に対応していません。
>
> - ウェブサイトが `autocomplete="off"` を `<form>` に設定しており、かつそのフォーム内にユーザー名とパスワードの入力欄が含まれていた場合、ブラウザーはログイン情報を記憶するか尋ねてきて、ユーザーが同意すれば、次回の訪問時にログイン欄を自動入力します。
> - ウェブサイトが `autocomplete="off"` をユーザー名とパスワードの `<input>` 欄に設定していた場合でも、ブラウザーはログイン情報を記憶するか尋ねてきて、ユーザーが同意すれば、次回の訪問時にログイン欄を自動入力します。
>
> この挙動は Firefox 38 以降、 Google Chrome 34 以降、 Internet Explorer 11 以降で共通です。

つまり、WebブラウザーはHTMLコンテンツ作者よりも利用者の意思を尊重します。利用者が値の保存を望めば、補完されるでしょう。

同ページには

> ### 自動補完を無効化するツール
>
> jquery.disableAutoFill は input の `name` 属性を既定でランダム化します。フォームが投稿されると、プラグインは本来の名前を復元します。これはすべてのブラウザーで (サードパーティの自動補完の拡張機能を含めて) 自動補完を防ぎます。

が紹介されているように、毎回`name`や`id`が異なれば、Webブラウザーは補完できなくなります。

Comment: jquery.disableAutoFill ですが、こちらユーザ名、パスワード名の入力の2か所の部分にしか対応しておりませんが、通常のメールフォームの場合、項目が多数あるので、jsで対応可能かとも感じます。試してみます。ありがとうございます

Comment: jquery.disableAutoFill ですが、毎回nameやidが変わるのですが、メールフォームの場合、毎回入力した項目名が変わることになり、自動返信など行っている場合、自動返信メールが送信できなくなりました。表示はしなくなったのですが、jquery.disableAutoFillはログインフォーム向けなのかと思います

Comment: @st-rise jquery.disableAutoFill はヒントとして挙げただけで、適用例のつもりもありません。あとはWeb閲覧者に対してどれだけ強い意志をもって嫌がらせを行うか次第だと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Edgeのバグかと思います。サイト側で対策できるとしたら、これらの`input`要素に [`autocomplete="name"`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-name) を付けてEdgeがクレジットカードのフィールドだと誤解しないようにすることでしょうか。

Comment: autocomplete="name"をつけtのですが、Edgeがクレジットカードと認識します。
type="text"に対してEdgeが反応しているようです